# why I am getting (TypeError: must be real number, not list) while doing gridsearchcv?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, svm

I am trying to make ML model for cifar dataset; this is the code:

```
clf = SVC(kernel='rbf')
grid = {'C':[1,10,100,1000],'gamma':[[1,10,100,1000]]}
res = gs(clf,grid)
res.fit(x_train,y_train)
#clf.fit(x_train,cls_train)
#y_pred = clf.predict(x_test)
print(res.best_estimator_)
```

Comment: Please provide the complete stacktrace

Answer (score 0):

In the params for the grid seach try to give single dimensional list as mentioned below.

`python grid = {'C':[1,10,100,1000],'gamma':[1,10,100,1000]}`